# Copy entire columns (based on specific headers) from one sheet to another (in other order) does not work on Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba

got a problem i can't overcome alone:

Below code works fine on my Win 8.1 running Excel 2013 Pro (32-bit). It fails miserably on Win 10 with Excel 365 (also 32-bit).

The VBA console is highlighting names i'm assigning to the columns (SRO, Desc, Status, Project ect.) in blue and the "Private Sub Generate()" in yellow.

```
Private Sub Generate()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Imported Data").Activate

'tis where You select what columns You want to copy and name them

            SRO = WorksheetFunction.Match("SroNum", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            Desc = WorksheetFunction.Match("Description", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            Status = WorksheetFunction.Match("Status", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            Project = WorksheetFunction.Match("srouf_platform", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            SROlead = WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            OpenDate = WorksheetFunction.Match("CreateDate", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            CloseDate = WorksheetFunction.Match("Close Date", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            TPT = WorksheetFunction.Match("SroTPTinDays", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            STATUSnew = WorksheetFunction.Match("srouf_intel_sro_status", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            WRKstat = WorksheetFunction.Match("Status Code", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            OpCode = WorksheetFunction.Match("OperationCode", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            Priority = WorksheetFunction.Match("Priority Code", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            OpPartner = WorksheetFunction.Match("OperationPartnerName", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            DUT = WorksheetFunction.Match("LineSerialNum", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            OpDesc = WorksheetFunction.Match("OperationDescription", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            OpStatus = WorksheetFunction.Match("OperationStatus", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            CreatedBy = WorksheetFunction.Match("CreatedBy", Rows("1:1"), 0)


'adding new sheet - CROPPED DATA
        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Cropped Data"

'tis where You copy selected columns to CROPPED DATA in specific A-Q order
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(SRO).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("A1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(Desc).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("B1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(Status).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("C1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(Project).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("D1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(SROlead).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("E1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(OpenDate).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("F1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(CloseDate).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("G1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(TPT).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("H1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(STATUSnew).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("I1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(WRKstat).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("J1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(Priority).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("K1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(CreatedBy).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("L1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(OpPartner).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("M1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(DUT).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("N1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(OpCode).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("O1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(OpDesc).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("P1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(OpStatus).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("Q1")

End Sub
```

The error I get is:

> Compile error in hidden module: Generate.

Any other alternatives?
How ought i rephrase this, so excel 365 would work?
I need this code to be as light as possible - tons of data are being processed.

The task stands: find specific header columns in sheet "Imported Data" and copy them to new sheet "cropped data" but in a different order (and not all of them!).

Comment: P.S. The columns in Sheet("Imported Data") often will be in random order (one day "SroNum" column may be in column A, the other B etc. - thus i was using worksheetfunction.match

Answer (score -1):

Two things cause this problem:

1. In Excel 365 "SRO" is a predefined constant - thus i needed to change it to SR0
2. Excel 365 needs to have all of the values (like SR0, Descpt, Stats etc.) predefined with DIM (as simple as that):

```
Private Sub Generate2()

'warning! it's ZERO in all SR0, not O!
        Dim SR0 As Double
        Dim Descpt As Double
        Dim Stats As Double
        Dim Project As Double
        Dim SR0lead As Double
        Dim OpenDate As Double
        Dim CloseDate As Double
        Dim TPT As Double
        Dim STATUSnew As Double
        Dim WRKstat As Double
        Dim OpCode As Double
        Dim Priority As Double
        Dim OpPartner As Double
        Dim DUT As Double
        Dim OpDesc As Double
        Dim OpStatus As Double
        Dim CreatedBy As Double

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Imported Data").Activate

'tis where You select what columns You want to copy and name them
            SR0 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("SroNum", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            Descpt = WorksheetFunction.Match("Description", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            Stats = WorksheetFunction.Match("Status", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            Project = WorksheetFunction.Match("srouf_platform", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            SR0lead = WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            OpenDate = WorksheetFunction.Match("CreateDate", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            CloseDate = WorksheetFunction.Match("Close Date", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            TPT = WorksheetFunction.Match("SroTPTinDays", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            STATUSnew = WorksheetFunction.Match("srouf_intel_sro_status", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            WRKstat = WorksheetFunction.Match("Status Code", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            OpCode = WorksheetFunction.Match("OperationCode", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            Priority = WorksheetFunction.Match("Priority Code", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            OpPartner = WorksheetFunction.Match("OperationPartnerName", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            DUT = WorksheetFunction.Match("LineSerialNum", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            OpDesc = WorksheetFunction.Match("OperationDescription", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            OpStatus = WorksheetFunction.Match("OperationStatus", Rows("1:1"), 0)
            CreatedBy = WorksheetFunction.Match("CreatedBy", Rows("1:1"), 0)

'adding new sheet - CROPPED DATA
           Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Cropped Data"

'tis where You copy selected columns to CROPPED DATA in specific A-Q order
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(SR0).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("A1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(Descpt).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("B1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(Stats).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("C1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(Project).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("D1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(SR0lead).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("E1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(OpenDate).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("F1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(CloseDate).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("G1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(TPT).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("H1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(STATUSnew).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("I1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(WRKstat).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("J1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(Priority).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("K1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(CreatedBy).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("L1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(OpPartner).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("M1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(DUT).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("N1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(OpCode).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("O1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(OpDesc).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("P1")
            Sheets("Imported Data").Columns(OpStatus).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cropped Data").Range("Q1")
```

Hope this helps anyone else :)